# Should I indicate qualifying categories on the product top-level landing page?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-expectation

I'm working with a store landing page that displays the main five product categories.  All five category images are displayed inline, and are same height and width. Each has an appropriate label and icon/picture. Essentially, each product category is the same as/equal to the others in importance.

Only three of the product categories qualify for the promotion that will be displayed as a full-width banner/hero at the top of the page, directly above all five product categories. The banner has a link with details as to what qualifies, legal stuff, etc.

Should I call out the three product categories that qualify? Perhaps changing the icon the brand color/white rather than grey/white or in some way highlighting them?

My concern is that the different colors will just be seen as discordant rather than indicative of relevance to the promotion.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I think your second version with the **"get rewarded"** label should suffice to convey the message you want to give.

However, there's some cognitive load that makes the message a bit hard to grasp at simple sight, and it's because of the [scrim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrim_%28material%29) or semi-transparency you're using on the images. Many times, the semi-transparency is used for disabled elements and IMHO, this semi-transparency works this way in your samples, your labels are close, yet not enough.

I'd try notching down the scrim a bit, or even use imagery and scrims as [Material Design suggests](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/imagery.html#). You may find that simply taking off the scrim would be just what you need.

As for scrim techniques, Material has some good recommendations and guidelines, but you culd take a look to NNG's article **[Ensure High Contrast for Text Over Images](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/text-over-images/)** which deals with some techniques, examples and explanations for what you need.

In the end, it all comes down to *test, test, test!*

Answer (score 0):

Your concern about color confusion or mis-coding is valid. Instead of color, consider adding a symbol to the button(e.g.,Blue ribbon with a gold center or a plain blue ribbon) to those categories that have a "deal". Here is an examples using a gold centered and a plain blue ribbon.[image: Buttons with blue ribbon = categfory with a deal]

Comment: The notoriously poor [usability of icons](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/) would not tend to indicate that adding a ribbon to indicate "deal" would mean anything more than a color shade.

Comment: mousing over the button with the deal could reveal a message "sale items" that there are sale items under this category...

Comment: Bye the way, the button designs suggested in the question need to be tested with the target audience to validate user understanding of the intended meaning.

Comment: Okay, I'm really glad to know I'm on the right track. While I was waiting for replies, I went with something I thought would be indicative but fairly unobtrusive.  I updated the original question with another image.